# ReactJS app that consumes PHP API with server-side fallback?

Tags: php, reactjs, api, lumen

I have PHP back-end API and I wanna connect it to a React front-end. The back-end and front-end is completely separate. Is there anyway to create a fallback in case javascript is disabled? Because turning off Javascript at the moment just returns a blank page which isn't really that great.

Is it even possible when both ends are completely separate and you're just fetching from an API? I'm very new to React so I'm not sure how people normally build React apps/websites but surely they don't just "ignore" users with JS disabled? Last time I did front-end developing that was a big no no, maybe times have changed...

Either way, is it possible somehow with my current "setup"? Would it be possible to use node.js and express to render the front-end React and serving it via nginx or something?

Comment: I would guess that the vast majority of react apps don't have a no-js fallback. Maybe some big enough companies do...

Comment: It would depend on what the use case is. Is it a 'static' website that is enhanced with react? Or is it a web app built on react? If it's the latter then it wouldn't make much sense to have a non-js fallback, because the whole point of the app is to be interactive. If it's the former, you would likely need some form of server side rendering to get the HTML generated then bind the JS on load.

Comment: It would be built on React since the back-end is just an API that returns JSON data. But it feels incorrect to not have any kind of fallback. I guess another option would be to build a PHP app that uses the already existing PHP API and only use React to "enhance" the UI/UX.

Comment: You can still build the website in react, but if it's making calls to an API to populate the data then you will need some form of serverside rendering to make that call and render the html with the results. You can still keep the API and FE separate, and the SSR doesn't need to be done in PHP, and would actually probably be best done in node.js.